# Open a POST reply in mobile safari

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

this is my question:
I make a POST requesto to www.aaa.com :

```
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@" bll bla ",importo];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.aaa.com"];

NSLog(@"POST: %@",post); 
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
    allowLossyConversion:YES];
... bla bla bla....
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
[request setValue:userAgent forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
httpResponse = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] 
    initWithRequest:request 
    delegate:self];
[connection release];
```

i receive a response and all is ok!
but in

```
- (void) connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

i want open the response page in mobile safari, not in a uiwebview, probably i must change approach, anyone have suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open URL in Safari, call:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: yourUrl];
```

Comment: Is there a way to open an `NSURLRequest` in safari?

Comment: @mtmurdock you probably need to use URL property for that